# Implementing common methods across multiple Steps Files in Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests, cucumber-junit

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.8</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.8</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

specification

```
|-src
 |-test
  |-java
   |-MyFeature1
     |-MyFeature1Steps.java 
     |-MyFeature1Test.java
   |-MyFeature2
     |-MyFeature2Steps.java 
     |-MyFeature2Test.java
  |-resources
    |-Features
    |-MyFeature1
      |-MyFeature1.feature
    |-MyFeature2
      |-MyFeature2.feature
```

In `MyFeature1Test.java` , I have this:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, features = "classpath:Features" , tags = "@registration", glue={"classpath:MyFeature1/MyFeature1Steps.java"})
    public class MyFeature1Test
    {   
    }
```

Scenario File `MyFeature1.feature`:

```
@smoke
Feature: Feature 1

Background: 
Given User is Logged in

Scenario: 
Given Go to this Page
When Perform this action
```

Steps class: `MyFeature1Steps.java`

```
public class MyFeature1Steps

@Given("^User is Logged in$")
public void navigateAndLogin()
{
    //Implemention
}

@Given("^Go to this Page$")
public void goToThisPage()
{
    //Implemention
}

@Then("^Perform this action$")
public void verifyAbc()
{
    //Implemention
}
```

In `MyFeature2Test.java`, I have this:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, features = "classpath:Features" , tags = "@registration", glue={"classpath:MyFeature1/MyFeature2Steps.java"})
    public class MyFeature2Test
    {   
    }
```

Scenario File `MyFeature2.feature`:

```
@Abc
Feature: Feature 2

Background: 
Given User is Logged in

Scenario: 
Given Go to that Page
When Perform that action
```

Another steps class: `MyFeature2Steps.java`:

```
public class MyFeature1Steps

@Given("^User is Logged in$")
public void navigateAndLogin()
{
    //Implemention
}

@Given("^Go to that Page$")
public void goToThatPage()
{
    //Implemention
}

@Then("^Perform that action$")
public void performThis()
{
    //Implemention
}
```

So here I need to write background(Given User is Logged in) implementation method(`navigateAndLogin()`) in all my steps file(`MyFeature1Steps.java`, `MyFeature2Steps.java`, etc).

Can I write the method of 'Given User is Logged in' at common place, such as beforeAll in testNG or may be before suite?

Answer (score 0):

To share steps among different steps classes you can implement one of the following options:

**Helper class**

You can define a helper class which you can then add to any of your steps classes and it will be used for sharing data. So have a look at the example class below:

```
class KnowsTheDomain {
    private Account myAccount;
    private CashSlot cashSlot;

    public Account getMyAccount() {
        if (myAccount == null){
            myAccount = new Account();
        }

    return myAccount;

    }

    public CashSlot getCashSlot() {
        if (cashSlot == null){
            cashSlot = new CashSlot();
        }

        return cashSlot;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it inside your steps classes like this:

```
public AccountSteps() {
    helper = new KnowsTheDomain();
}
```

**Dependency Injection**

This is the preferable and much more cleaner way to do that. This topic is fairly wide and I won't attempt to cover any of it here but just to give some idea what topic to look for, below is a list of tools that you might want to consider:

- picocontainer
- guice
- spring

Also have a look [here](https://cucumber.io/blog/2015/07/08/polymorphic-step-definitions).